# Convert Value type to Map in Golang?

Tags: reflection, go

I'm getting this return value from a function call in the "reflect" package:

`< map[string]string Value >`.

Wondering if I can access the actual map inside the return value and if so, how?

EDIT:

So this is where I'm making the call which returns the Value object. 
It returns `[< map[string]string Value >]` to which I grab the first object in that array. However, I'm not sure how to convert `[< map[string]string Value >]` into a regular map.

```
view_args := reflect.ValueOf(&controller_ref).MethodByName(action_name).Call(in)
```

Comment: Can you give us a bit more code sample?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Most reflect `Value` objects can be converted back to a `interface{}` value using the [`.Interface()` method](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface).

After obtaining this value, you can assert it back to the map you want. Example ([play](http://play.golang.org/p/0ae0poz9w1)):

```
m := map[string]int{"foo": 1, "bar": 3}
v := reflect.ValueOf(m)
i := v.Interface()
a := i.(map[string]int)

println(a["foo"]) // 1
```

In the example above, `m` is your original map and `v` is the reflected value. The interface value `i`, acquired by the `Interface` method is asserted to be of type `map[string]int` and this value is used as such in the last line.

Comment: Perfect, I'm sure the one below works, too, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 8):

To turn the value in a `reflect.Value` into an `interface{}`, you use `iface := v.Interface()`. Then, to access that, you use a [type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) or [type switch](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches).

If you know you're getting a `map[string]string` the assertion is simply `m := iface.(map[string]string)`. If there's a handful of possibilities, the type switch to handle them all looks like:

```
switch item := iface.(type) {
case map[string]string:
    fmt.Println("it's a map, and key \"key\" is", item["key"])
case string:
    fmt.Println("it's a string:", item)
default:
    // optional--code that runs if it's none of the above types
    // could use reflect to access the object if that makes sense
    // or could do an error return or panic if appropriate
    fmt.Println("unknown type")
}
```

Of course, that only works if you can write out all the concrete types you're interested out in the code. If you don't know the possible types at compile time, you have to use methods like `v.MapKeys()` and `v.MapIndex(key)` to work more with the `reflect.Value`, and, in my experience, that involves a long time looking at [the `reflect` docs](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) and is often verbose and pretty tricky.