# How should I pass param in golang?

Tags: go, reflection

I have the follow whole codes:

I hope that string convert map in golang, and use golang reflect.

The following code have simpled from my project.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    jsonStr := `{"name": "thinkerou", "age": 31, "balance": 3.14}`

    var a map[string]interface{}
    var value reflect.Value = reflect.ValueOf(&a)

    // call function and pass param
    f(jsonStr, value)

    // print result
    fmt.Println(value.Kind(), value.Interface())
}

func f(v string, value reflect.Value) {
    personMap := make(map[string]interface{})

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(v), &personMap)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    value = reflect.Indirect(value)
    value = reflect.MakeMap(value.Type())
    for k, v := range personMap {
        // set key/value
        value.SetMapIndex(reflect.ValueOf(k), reflect.ValueOf(v))
    }

    // print result
    fmt.Println(value.Kind(), value.Interface())
}
```

and run it and will get the result:

```
map map[age:31 balance:3.14 name:thinkerou]
ptr &map[]
```

I hope the follow result:

```
map map[age:31 balance:3.14 name:thinkerou]
map map[age:31 balance:3.14 name:thinkerou]
```

How should I pass `reflect.Value` param? thanks!

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something. I can't understand what you are trying to achieve here by reflection etc. What you need ultimately seems to have been achieved by just `json.Unmarshal([]byte(v), &personMap)` See https://play.golang.org/p/fPEikxh0lDv Can you kindly explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get your map from the interface, using [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

```
a := i.(map[string]interface{})
```

See "[Convert Value type to Map in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20714739/6309)"

I have modified your [code here](https://play.golang.org/p/R724_1G3tnF).
Note that I don't try to mutate the `f(value)` argument, but I return it instead.

```
func f(v string, value reflect.Value) reflect.Value {
  ...
  return value 
}
```

So the code becomes:

```
value = f(jsonStr, value)
fmt.Println(value.Kind(), value.Interface().(map[string]interface{}))
```